# ICollection<object> - como criar e usar objetos dentro da coleção

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

Estou a trabalhar num projeto usando MVC5 e EntityFramwork 6. Segui um tutorial para criar uma base de dados a partir dos meus modelos.

Exemplo de um modelo:

```
public class Side
{

    public Side()
    {

    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

    public int Content { get; set; }
}
```

Como faço agora para adicionar um comentário para `ICollection<Comment> Comments`?

Pelo que andei a ler, tenho de criar uma função `Add()`, mas não estou a perceber onde.

Também queria saber como isto funciona a nivel da base de dados, como são os comentários adicionados à base de dados? (tenho uma tabela para `Comment` e `Side`) e tenho o `Comment` definido assim:

```
public class Comment
{
    public Comment()
    {

    }

    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int AuthorID { get; set; }
    public DateTime DatePublished { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateEdited { get; set; }
    public bool edited { get; set; }
    public int VotesUp { get; set; }
    public int VotesDown { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Como faço agora para adicionar um comentário para ICollection Comments?

Supondo que este comentário é feito a nível apenas de código, você pode adicionar um `Comment` através do seu *Controller* da seguinte forma:

```
var contexto = new MeuSistemaContext();
// Vamos primeiro trazer um Side qualquer
var side = db.Sides.FirstOrDefault(); // Aqui estou trazendo o primeiro Side disponível na base de dados

// Vamos agora criar um novo Comment
var novoComment = new Comment 
{
    Content = "Oi, eu sou um comentário",
    DatePublished = DateTime.Now,
    DateEdited = DateTime.Now,
    edited = False,
    VotesUp = 0,
    VotesDown = 0,
    Side = side // Esta é a parte mais importante. Aqui faço a referência entre Side e o novo Comment
};

// Agora adiciono o novo objeto ao contexto
db.Comments.Add(novoComment); // Você não precisa implementar este método Add(). Ele já existe em DbContext.
                              // Você só precisa adicionar uma referência a System.Data.Entity no seu código para usar.
db.SaveChanges(); // Aqui salvamos todas as alterações de contexto.
```

> Também queria saber como isto funciona a nivel da base de dados, como são os comentários adicionados à base de dados?

O exemplo acima resume como é a inserção mais básica possível, mas estamos falando de um sistema em ASP.NET MVC e, portanto, este comentário virá da tela através de um formulário enviado por `POST`.

Considerando que você montou um formulário assim:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SideID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AuthorID)
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Content)
}
```

E um método no *Controller* que receberá o comentário assim:

```
public ActionResult AdicionarComentario(Comment comment)
{ ... }
```

A lógica a ser implementada é muito semelhante ao exemplo que coloquei acima, ou seja:

```
public ActionResult AdicionarComentario(Comment comment)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) // Aqui ocorre a validação dos dados
    {
        db.Comments.Add(comment); // Aqui, a adição do registro ao contexto
        db.SaveChanges(); // Aqui efetivamente ocorre a persistência dos dados
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    // Se o código falhar na validação, ocorrerá a linha abaixo.
    return View(comment);
}
```

Comment: obrigado, muito completa a sua resposta!

Answer (score -1):

A classe comment necessita ter uma alteração, você vai precisar fazer relação 1-n de side para comment, e devera colocar o side no comentário,
e para adicionar um comentário ao side você deve adicionar desta maneira.

Recomendo ler a documentação da MSDN que é bem explicativa quanto ao assunto.

[msdn ICollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/92t2ye13(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             var side = new Side();
             side.Comments.add(new Comment());
        }
    }

 public class Comment
    {
        public Comment()
        {

        }

        public string Content { get; set; }
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int Side_ID { get; set; }
        public int AuthorID { get; set; }
        public DateTime DatePublished { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateEdited { get; set; }
        public bool edited { get; set; }
        public int VotesUp { get; set; }
        public int VotesDown { get; set; }

        public virtual Side Side { get; set; }

    }

 public class Side
    {

        public Side()
        {            
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

        public int Content { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: side.Comments.add(new Comment()); o **add()** não está implementado

Comment: Verifique se os using estão corretos. using System.Collections.Generic

Comment: estavam corretas, mas eu decidi optar por outra abordagem